# How to pass CSS keyframe name as variable?

Tags: css, css-variables

I have a css animation keyframe:

```
  @keyframes first-movement {
    0%, 100% {
      opacity: 0;
      transform: scale(0) rotate(0deg);
    }
    20%, 99% {
      opacity: 1;
      transform: scale(1) rotate(180deg);
    }
  }
```

When I use it as common, everything works fine

```
  rect {
    animation-name: first-movement;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-duration: 8s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    transform-origin: 40px 40px;
  }
```

But when I try to send as CSS var it does not work

```
  rect {
    animation-name: var(--main-animation);
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-duration: 8s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    transform-origin: 40px 40px;
  }
```

This is how I can assign var,

```
  #load-area > use:nth-child(1) {
    --main-animation: first-movement;
  }
```

It does not throw error or any kind of clue to investigate, Which is the error?

**UPDATE:**
I add the full code, remove the marked line to break it.

As I mention, I do this with `animation-duration` and it works perfect, but it is more complicated calculate times, instead I create new keyframes with the necessary timing (I have five keyframes).

UPDATE 2:
This is a Chrome BUG, the code works perfectly on Firefox
[image]

```css
      @keyframes first {
        0%, 100% {
          opacity: 0;
          transform: scale(0) rotate(0deg);
        }
        20%, 99% {
          opacity: 1;
          transform: scale(1) rotate(180deg);
        }
      }
      
      @keyframes second {
        0%, 20%, 100% {
          opacity: 0;
          transform: scale(0) rotate(0deg);
        }
        40%, 99% {
          opacity: 1;
          transform: scale(1) rotate(180deg);
        }
      }
      
       #circle,
      #cross,
      #square,
      #triangle {
        opacity: 0;
      }

      rect {
        animation-name: var(--main-animation);
        animation-timing-function: linear;
        animation-duration: 8s;
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        transform-origin: 40px 40px;
      }

      #load-area > use:nth-child(1) {
        --main-animation: first;
      }
      
      #load-area > use:nth-child(1) {
        --main-animation: second;
      }
```

```html
    <div style="background-color: aliceblue">
      <svg viewBox="-20 -20 600 200" id="main">
        <defs id="test">

          <rect width="80" height="80" id="circle" fill="red" />
          <rect width="80" height="80" id="square" fill="pink" />
          <rect width="80" height="80" id="cross" fill="blue" />
          <rect width="80" height="80" id="triangle" fill="green" />
        </defs>

        <g id="load-area">
          <use x="0" xlink:href="#circle" />
          <use x="100" xlink:href="#square" />
          <use x="200" xlink:href="#cross" />
          <use x="300" xlink:href="#triangle" />
        </g>
      </svg>
    </div>
```

Comment: You are probably calling var(--main-animation) where --main-animation is not defined.

Comment: can you share a full example

Comment: Can you share the relevant part of the html?

Comment: This is related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63203286/how-to-change-css-class-to-an-use-children-inside-a-svg/63203440#63203440 it is for an SVG, it works perfect with `animation-duration` but it does not work with `animation-name`

Comment: it seems to be a chrome bug, works fine on firefox https://jsfiddle.net/0j8wsutk/

Comment: @TemaniAfif  you are correct, this is a "Google Chrome bug", I will add a image gif with the difference, NICE JOB !!! Hi5. !!